# How to pass file path with '/' to route laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How can we pass file path to route like this,

```
<a href={{route('route.name',['path'=>'uploads/xyx/'.$id.'/'.$attachment_name])}}>download</a>
```

However, I would like this to hit

```
Route::get('download/{path},'Controller')->name('route.name')
```

When I hit this route my url got transformed somehow like this -> **download/uploads/44/filename** which is causing not found exception!
I want to pass the path as a parameter, where slashes should have to be ignored! so that I can get full path in my controller!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-encoded-forward-slashes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation you can do this:

> "The Laravel routing component allows all characters except `/`. You must explicitly allow `/` to be part of your placeholder using a where condition regular expression"

```
Route::get('download/{path}', ...)->where('path', '.*');
```

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Routing - Parameters - Encoding Forward Slashes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-encoded-forward-slashes)

Answer (score 2):

use get `parameter`  remove `{path}`

```php
Route::get('download,'Controller')->name('route.name')
```

in blade

```php
<a href={{route('route.name',['path'=>'uploads/xyx/'.$id.'/'.$attachment_name])}}>download</a>
```

this will generate url like `route.name?path=download/uploads/44/filename`

still u will get data in controller like `$request->path`

Comment: It worked, seems quite more user friendly I believe!

Comment: @MuhammadTariq yes in `get` method usually data send like this

Comment: I am only concened with security issue if there could be like to expose storage path to users?

Comment: `concened with security` then use `post` don't use `get`